# How To Get Particular Security Advisory Repository in Graphql

Tags: api, github, graphql, github-api

[I have Tried](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/securityadvisory/)

I have tried this code

```
`# Type queries into this side of the screen, and you will 
# see intelligent typeaheads aware of the current GraphQL type schema, 
# live syntax, and validation errors highlighted within the text.

# We'll get you started with a simple query showing your username!


query {
  securityAdvisories(orderBy: {field: PUBLISHED_AT, direction: DESC}, first: 2) {
    nodes {
      description
      ghsaId
      summary
      publishedAt
    }
  }
}
```

And got the below response

```
{
  "data": {
    "securityAdvisories": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "description": "In Symfony before 2.7.51, 2.8.x before 2.8.50, 3.x before 3.4.26, 4.x before 4.1.12, and 4.2.x before 4.2.7, when service ids allow user input, this could allow for SQL Injection and remote code execution. This is related to symfony/dependency-injection.",
          "ghsaId": "GHSA-pgwj-prpq-jpc2",
          "summary": "Critical severity vulnerability that affects symfony/dependency-injection",
          "publishedAt": "2019-11-18T17:27:31Z"
        },
        {
          "description": "Tapestry processes assets `/assets/ctx` using classes chain `StaticFilesFilter -> AssetDispatcher -> ContextResource`, which doesn't filter the character `\\`, so attacker can perform a path traversal attack to read any files on Windows platform.",
          "ghsaId": "GHSA-89r3-rcpj-h7w6",
          "summary": "Moderate severity vulnerability that affects org.apache.tapestry:tapestry-core",
          "publishedAt": "2019-11-18T17:19:03Z"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But i want to get the response for specific security advisory [like this](https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-wmx6-vxcf-c3gr)

i.e i want to get graphql response for specific id for below example url ID is GHSA-wmx6-vxcf-c3gr

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to use the `securityAdvisory()` query.

```
query {
securityAdvisory(ghsaId: "GHSA-wmx6-vxcf-c3gr") {
  ghsaId
  summary
    }
}
```

If you need to use the `securityAdvisories()` query for some reason, you simply have to add an [`identifier:`](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/graphql/reference/enums#securityadvisoryidentifiertype). The following query should get the distinct entry for `GHSA-wmx6-vxcf-c3gr`.

```
query {
securityAdvisory(ghsaId: "GHSA-wmx6-vxcf-c3gr") {
  ghsaId
  summary
    }
}
```